# C# SQL Query with ProgressBar

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, progress-bar

Connecting to SQL Server and send a Query is pretty simple . But I want to know how it's possible to relate it with Progress Bars .

I mean when the Query is executing , the bar is progressing ...

Comment: you need something countable for your progress bar.  What's your query?

Comment: The query is just Deleting/Adding some rows on SQL .

Comment: well if you know how many times you're doing your operation you can set the progress bar value to (num/maxnum)

Comment: Oh yeah right . I got it working , thank you Pale :p

Answer (score 0):

For example you know number of your query. 
Before all of that, you set maximum and minimum of ProgressRing.

```
ProgressRing.Maximum = 100;
ProgressRing.Minimum = 0;
```

and before the loop you define a counter type of int. 
in the loop that you need code like this

```
ring.Value = (100 * counter) / query.Count;
```